# I am trying to select and click a button within a website using Selenium but there are multiple button with the same class

Tags: python-3.x

I am just trying to play about with Selenium and wondered whether I could click any clickable object but found myself unable to click many objects (buttons).

So far I have been trying these:

```
(By.XPATH, ('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[26]'))
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Soccer").click()
```

This is the html code I am trying to click from, I am trying to click the "Soccer" button.

```
<b>
    <div class="wn-Classification" style="">Rugby League<div class="wn-Classification_FavIcon "></div></div>
    <div class="wn-Classification">Rugby Union<div class="wn-Classification_FavIcon "></div></div>
    <div class="wn-Classification" style="">Snooker<div class="wn-Classification_FavIcon "></div></div>
    <div class="wn-Classification" style="">Soccer<div class="wn-Classification_FavIcon "></div></div>
</b>
```

Error:

The problem is: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Soccer"}`

Anyone able to help?

What intrigues the most is that the following if statement goes through and then says that it cannot find the file but the path is the same:

```py
if EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[26]'))):
                self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[26]").click()
            else:
                print("hm")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you "41 72 6c" for your support. 
You were right all along and I just went on your thought and tried this:

```py
if EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[26]'))):
                WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[26]')))
                self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[26]').click()
```

And it worked.

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `find_element` runs too quickly before the page is fully loaded. Try to wait for elements to appear and set a timer (in this example for like 10 seconds). Make sure to add the missing imports then.

The webdriver will wait for a page to load by default:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_link_text("Soccer")))
```

If thats not the problem there are two ways to do this -

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wn-Classification')[3].click()
```

or you go for

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Soccer').click()
```

Comment: None of the options are working, I still get the same error. ):

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to change my code. I hadnt tried that line before because I used but I am getting same error: "The problem is: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Soccer"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)."

I had tried:
while True:
 EC.presence_of_all_element_located

and still same error

Comment: @DeavyDante have you added the missing imports like `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: Yeah, I have these imported:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains

Comment: It always worked before because I always use XPATH, I think it is maybe all buttons have same class then the only option would be finding by name but it returns missing element error

Comment: and what if you add an id to the elements? then you could go for `find_element_by_id(...)`

Comment: I do not have permission to modify the webpage.
Else I would have made it alot simpler. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: That was the very first one I tried. 
I now tried "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[26]/text()" and got same results.